# POLARS: pycharm exited with following error code : -1073741819 (0xC0000005) while converting lazyframes to polars dataframe using lf.collect()

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-evaluation, python-polars, lazyframe

I have a piece of code which is performing some computations on top of lazy frames. I have the output stored in form of lazy frames in a dictionary. At the end, I am converting the outputs to pandas dataframe and writing them as feather files.

During this process, execution is being terminated abruptly without any traceback with the following error code:

Process exited with the following error code: -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I am not expecting the above error, help me with the reasons for the cause and how to fix it.

```
collect_stime = timeit.default_timer()
for key, lf in lf_dict.items():
    lf_dict[key] = lf.collect().to_pandas()
collect_etime = timeit.default_timer()
```

Comment: What is the code block you're running?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Wayoshi, I have updated the piece of code where I was encountering the error. Please do let me know if you need any information further. Thank you!

Comment: I have also tried to execute the above block of code by removing to_pandas() conversion, still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: This windows error is often associated with permission to files and memory resources. Are you using Windows? What happen if you run your script as administrator? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/application-error-0xc0000005/6224ae45-a251-4f21-b076-74524618d00a

Comment: @jlandercy, Yes, I am using windows. I am not the privileged user to run this as an administrator. Would there be any alternative to fix this ?

Comment: You need to isolate which resource causes this error first. It is impossible to tell what happening based on information in your post. Once you have found it try to gain privileged access or create a copy of files in your user folder.